# Custom Styling of mdToolTip

Tags: css, angular

I have the following code in an Angular project

```
 <input class="form-control" type="number" [(ngModel)]="cons.failPercent" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                         mdTooltip="Typically valves can be repaired three times before they need to be replaced"
                         mdTooltipPosition="right"
                         autofocus/>
```

In my component I have

```
    @Component({
  templateUrl: './ownership-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ownership-form.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

and in my CSS I have

```
.md-tooltip{
  color:yellow !important;
  height:auto;
}
```

But it does not appear to be styling the tooltip. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your Angular version you'll need to use the `/deep/` or `::ng-deep` [combination selectors](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) to circumvent encapsulation. Alternatively, set the styling on your global stylesheet (commonly styles.scss).

Angular 2:

```
/deep/ .md-tooltip { ... }
```

Angular 4.3+:

```
::ng-deep .md-tooltip { ... }
```

[More info at Hackernoon](https://hackernoon.com/the-new-angular-ng-deep-and-the-shadow-piercing-combinators-deep-and-drop-4b088dbe459)

Comment: i added the height:auto to add line breaks, but in my string I have \n and it's still not adding line breaks, would you know why?

Comment: `\n` isn't HTML. Anyway, please don't ask new questions in comments. Also, thanks comments are discouraged. [Take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you're new to SO.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally scope your styles to the component in question.

Angular < v4.2

```css
:host /deep/ {
  .md-tooltip { ... }
}

:host >>> {
  .md-tooltip { ... }
}
```

Angular >= v4.2

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  .md-tooltip { ... }
}
```

If you remove your encapsulation from the component. The styles should still work. By adding `::ng-deep` inside the `:host(..)` it will emulate global css. But only in a downward piercing direction.

Angular is trying to promote component level styles. I would avoid moving code to the global stylesheets. If you visit a route which does not require the component in question then you are instantiating (loading code) for no reason.