# How to apply CSS to a mdTooltip inside a md-cell

Tags: css

I want to apply some `CSS` styling for the mdTooltip attribute in a md-cell of a cdk table.

Something like this:

```
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="Content">
  <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef md-sort-header> {{"Content" | translate}} </md-header-cell>
  <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row" class="content" mdTooltip="{{row['Content'] }}"> {{row['Content'] }} </md-cell>
</ng-container>
```

And in my css I did something like this

```
/deep/ .content[mdTooltip] {
     white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

But it is not working.

How can I fix this problem?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48509341/custom-styling-of-mdtooltip

Comment: @caiovisk I did try that solution, but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

After searching around, found the solution.

[Thanks for Axel's Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45862592/10323729)

Add an new attribute mdTooltipClass="foo".

```
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="Content">
      <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef md-sort-header> {{"Content" | translate}} </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row" mdTooltip="{{row['Content'] }}" mdTooltipClass="foo"> {{row['Content'] }} </md-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

CSS side

```
/deep/ .foo {
   white-space: pre-wrap;
```

}

The problem fixed.